# Using nvd3.js to draw a chart having stacked bar and line?

Tags: javascript, web, charts, interactive

For the nvd3 library, I can find bar and line combo but not a Stacked bar and line combo. Actually i can't find any example done with other JavaScript library except for Google Visualization which I also try to avoid. 
Any advise, sample code would be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For all those searching for the nvd3 answer to this question in the future, I was able to do this using the code laid out in this discussion.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/341

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to turn to [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). NVD3 is a framework/wrapper for D3. D3 is super powerful. Just about anything you can imagine you can accomplish. I found that it sometimes comes with a bit of a steep learning curve - especially for things that are a bit out of the ordinary.

You can see from examples on their site that they have a lot of options. You will probably even be able to find the exact chart you're looking for. But going this route will require a bit more learning than what NVD3 requires.